# Нужна ли запятая после слова "пятница"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

*Шоу, выход которого еженедельно приходится на пятницу(,) успешно продолжается.*

Нужна ли запятая после слова *пятница*? Если да, то по какому правилу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна по *правилу отделения придаточного предложения от главного* в сложноподчинённом предложении. Здесь придаточное предложение находится в середине главного, поэтому запятых две.